# First Semester CS Student needs help understanding statement in While loop

Tags: c++, c, while-loop

I normally post on DreamInCode.net but the site seems to be down right now. I'm a first semester CS student at De Anza. I don't understand really what the lineCount = 1; does in the else statement. I know what it does when I remove the statement but I don't understand it. If I could have someone explain it to me maybe in a different way that the book just happens to skip over, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {

    int num;
    int lineCount;

    printf ("\nEnter a starting number to decend between 1 and 100: ");
    scanf  ("%d", &num);

    if (num > 100)
        num = 100;

    lineCount = 0;

    while (num >= 0)
    {
        if (lineCount < 10)
            lineCount++;
        else
        {
            printf ("\n");
            lineCount = 1; // this line here is what I don't understand
        }
        printf ("%4d", num--);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`lineCount` isn't actually counting lines.  It's counting the number of numbers you've printed on the current line.

When that reaches 10, it breaks the line and starts a new one, resetting the counter to 1.  1 instead of 0 because you're placing another number on the new line.